# stop scrolling div from overlapping footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to have the div called #middlecta stop scrolling when it reaches #footer?

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/BP6rq/1522/

```
var pointOne = $("#form").offset().top;
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    $.fx.speeds.xslow = 750;
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > pointOne) {
        $("#middlecta").fadeIn('xslow').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $("#middlecta").fadeOut('xslow').removeClass('fixed').hide();
    }
    $("#middlecta-t").addClass("mob");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you want to have happen?

Comment: question reformatted

Comment: so that it doesn't overlap the footer?

Comment: yes, so that it doesn't overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely want to play around with the CSS. Setting a 100px margin may or may not be a good idea.  But, this should get you thinking on the right track at least.

```
var pointOne = $("#form").offset().top;
var pointTwo = $('#footer').position().top;
var $midCta = $("#middlecta");
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    $.fx.speeds.xslow = 750;
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > pointOne) {
        $midCta.fadeIn('xslow').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $midCta.fadeOut('xslow').removeClass('fixed').hide();
    }
    if ($midCta.offset().top > pointTwo) {
        $midCta.css('bottom', 150);
        $midCta.fadeOut('xslow').removeClass('fixed');
    }

    $midCta.addClass("mob");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BP6rq/1523/

Comment: oops remove the last fadeOut ;)

Comment: Accepted, going to play with this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. You will have to tweak it to your exact behavior, but the crux is to detect when it's reached the footer's top and then adjust the bottom css attribute accordingly.